# i`m not able to aws ec2 ssh it gives an error connection time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, ftp

i have create a aws ubuntu ec2 instance and gives elastic IP. and it's connect on ssh and FTP. but after half an hour it was disconnected and not connecting until now.
i have check add ssh with 22 port in security group inbound rules, also VPC is connect to subnet.
also add 0.0.0.0/0 with target internet getway in subnet Route table,  subnet Network ACL has also allow All traffic in inbound rules and outbound rules. and IAM user has only s3 bucket policies.
on the other hand i`m able to connect the RDS mysql database.

Comment: "it was disconnected and not connecting" -  what do you mean? Why was disconnected? Elastic IP?

Comment: yes it was disconnected after that it's not connecting. disconnected automatically, i`m working on ftp via filezilla then suddenly server connection lost and not connecting again. i tried  3 times. means i have create 3 time ec2 instance and it always disconnect in half an hour.

Comment: Are you the only user of this account? Maybe there is some automation running ever 30minut and disconnects it?

Comment: no, i'm the only user.

Comment: i don't think automation is working because connection loss in half an hour of creating instance